# "View of" vs "View from"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I would like to know the difference between "***a view of***" and "***a view from***". I have found a sentence related to it.

- We've reserved a double room for you with ***a view of*** the ocean.

So, couldn't you say "***a view from the ocean***" instead of "***a view of the ocean***"?

Answer (score 9):

*From* marks where the viewer is, *of* marks the object viewed.

> You'll have a great view ***of*** the sea ***from*** this room.
>
> The view ***of*** the city ***from*** the rooftop is great.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it would be improved by citing a supporting source and perhaps elaborating a bit. (Also, I'm confused by what spawned this series of comments on this answer talking about being off-topic on ELL... The answer doesn't mention anything of the sort.)

Answer (score 3):

**Of** usually means *"that is associated in some way with"*.

"This is the key **of** the door." = "This is the key **that is associated in some way with** the door." The way in which it is associated is that it locks and unlocks the door.

He held a bag **of** gold coins - He held a bag **associated in some way with** gold coins. The way in which it is associated is that it holds gold coins.

This is the view **of** the sea = This is the view that is **associated in some way with** the sea - the way in which it is associated is that when you see the view, you see the sea.

**From** usually tells you something about the origin of the noun and sometimes indicates a movement or change:

He made the sword **from** steel. - this tells you the origin of the metal used for the sword.

He walked **from** Italy to England- This says where he started, i.e. his origin.

The weather changed **from** rain to snow - This tells you what the weather was originally.

I saw the bird **from** the window. -This tells you your origin when you saw the bird.

**A view from the sea** = the view originating **in** the sea.